# Getting the text from a Listbox item

Tags: python, list, tkinter, listbox, pickle

I am creating a session list and pickling the sessions afterwards. This bit works but when I delete the session from the listbox with a right click menu, I need to be able to delete the item from the list I am pickling.

How do I get the text in the current listbox selection?

Here is my code:

```
class Main(self, root)
    def __init__(self):
        self.f2=Frame(root)
        self.f2.grid()
        Label(self.f2, text="Sesion Date:").grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.e=Entry(self.f2)
        self.e.grid(row=3, column=1)
        Button(self.f2, text="Add Session", command=lambda: self.session(client)).grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
        scrollbar=Scrollbar(self.f2)
        self.sessionbox=Listbox(self.f2, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.sessionbox.grid(row=5, columnspan=2)
        self.sessionmenu=Menu(self.sessionbox, tearoff=0)
        self.sessionmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=lambda: self.deleteSession(client))
        self.sessionbox.bind("<ButtonRelease-2>", self.sessionRightClick)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.sessionbox.yview)

    def session(self, client):
        if len(self.e.get()) == 0: 
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Add Session", "Please type a session date\nbefore submitting")
    else:
        self.sessionlist=[]
        self.sessionlist.append("%s" % (self.e.get()))
        self.sessionbox.insert(0, "%s" % (self.e.get()))
        with open("sessions", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(self.sessionlist, f)
        self.e.delete(0, END)
        self.row1+=1

    def deleteSession(self, client):
        try:
            sel=self.sessionbox.curselection()
            self.sessionbox.delete(sel)
            self.sessionlist.remove()
            with open("sessions", "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(self.sessionlist, f)
        except:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Delete Session", "No session selected!")

    def sessionRightClick(self, event):
        self.sessionmenu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

root=Tk()
app=Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get every item of the Listbox then you can use this. Keep in mind that what is returned is a `tuple`

```
.get(0, tk.END)
```

If you want the item(s) from the current selection then you can use this. Keep in mind that what is returned is a `tuple`

```
.curselection()
```

However, this only gives you the indexes of the selected items. To get the text simply use something like this. Using the index values from `.curselection()` to get the items from the entire selection

```
import tkinter as tk

l_box = tk.Listbox(...)
all_items = l_box.get(0, tk.END) # tuple with text of all items in Listbox
sel_idx = l_box.curselection() # tuple with indexes of selected items
sel_list = [all_items[item] for item in sel_idx] # list with text of all selected items
```

Comment: Typo sorry. Fixed answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
listbox = tk.listbox(...)

value=listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
print (value)
```